# my ssl certificate only work with 'www.example.com' and not with 'example.com'

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-2.4

I purchased a certificate that is valid for both www.example.com and example.com. My server is working only with "www.example.com" (ssl is working fine) but it is not showing anything at all when I type "example.com" on the browser. Here is my apache file config which basicly is the same virtualHost twice but with different ServerName

```
Define APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
Define SSLCERTIFICATE /etc/apache2/ssl/mycertificate.crt
Define SSLKEY /etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.key
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@example.com
                ServerName www.example.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile ${SSLCERTIFICATE}
                SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSLKEY}

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                <Directory />
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                </Directory>
                <Directory "/var/www/site2">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order Allow,Deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>


                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>

        # Same documetn root for example.com (without www)
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin admin@example.com
                ServerName example.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/site2/

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                SSLCertificateFile ${SSLCERTIFICATE}
                SSLCertificateKeyFile ${SSLKEY}

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                <Directory />
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                </Directory>
                <Directory "/var/www/site2">
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order Allow,Deny
                        Allow from all
                </Directory>


                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]"                                 nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown                                 downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Aditional Information:

- my site is hosted in a virtual machine in Azure (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)
- the domain name is from goDaddy
- there is another configuration file for http (port 80)

Comment: Can you somehow provide the actual domain of your site?

Comment: What do your logs say when your connection doesn't work?

Comment: How is your DNS set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your certificate is valid for both `example.com` and `www.example.com`, and both domains are configured to use the same directories, there is no reason that I can see for having them as separate VirtualHosts. I would remove the second VirtualHost and change the first one to look like this:

```
   <VirtualHost *:443>
            ServerAdmin admin@example.com
            ServerName www.example.com
            ServerAlias example.com

[the rest of the config should look the same as it does in your post]

    </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

the reason why you don't see the version without the www, is because you're using two wildcards for the IP `*:443` with two different domain names. Apache simply uses the first one to use the certificate with. 
From Apache Documentation[1]:

> The problem with using named virtual hosts over SSL is that named virtual hosts rely on knowing what hostname is being requested, and the request can't be read until the SSL connection is established. The ordinary behavior, then, is that the SSL connection is set up using the configuration in the default virtual host for the address where the connection was received.

To use a wildcard, you need then one IP per certificate. Each virtual IP will be used by Apache to redirect incoming SSL-encrypted request. 
To do so:

1. Add a virtual IP to the interface (if we assume it's eth0, add an alias to it)
2. Update the file `ports.conf`, add two entries:

   - NameVirtualHost IP1:443
   - NameVirtualHost IP2:443
3. Update your vHost to look like this:

   Site with the www

   ServerName www.site.com

   Site w/o the www

   ServerName site.com

**EDIT**
You can also redirect all incoming hits from "site.com" to "www.site.com". In order to do so, remove the vHost for `site.com` and add the following line:
    ServerAlias site.com

Doing so will instruct Apache to use the same vHost for both domains. 
If you want to redirect all incoming hits (http://example.com, and http://www.example.com) to the main, secured domain (https://www.example.com), consider adding the following instruction:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

*site.com replaced with example.com per Serverfault rules*

[1]https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: Thank you for you answer Razique, there is still one thing I do not understand: what should be those IP1 and IP3? I mean I have only one ip:  the virtual machine one. is it just to add 2 alias using my actual ip?

Comment: Hey, sorry, it was a typo. (IP3 is IP2), so you only add one IP. The VM main IP will be used with the "NameVirtualHost" 1 and the extra VIP you will add will be the one for the second "NameVirtualHost". The VIP will be an alias to the main IP yes. I would nevertheless suggest that you redirect all "site.com" incoming requests to the "www.site.com"; doing so will not only prevent Google from indexing two versions of the same website, but also make it easier for you.

Comment: See Jennny's answer: adding example.com is the way to go. You can also add a redirection - see my edit

Answer (score 0):

As you want to use SNI, you must enable it. Check if the

> NameVirtualHost *:443

is available somewhere in your configuration

But I think it should be better to add a serverAlias and the same root directory. You can select the difference by mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed by doing like [Jenny D](https://serverfault.com/users/120438/jenny-d) suggests and also redirecting from `mypage.com` to `www.mypage.com` and changing the 'www' CName in the goDaddy configuration (where my domain stands) to point my azure VM address.

Therefore neither modify the .htaccess nor using SNI was necessary in this case. Not sure if this is the best or ideal configuration but at least is working.